# Use fixed points with the NumPy Polynomial module

Tags: python, numpy, polynomial-math

I'm trying to use the [Polynomial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.polynomials.polynomial.html) module released with NumPy v1.4 to fit the data given in the example below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# data points to fit
x = np.array([11844.6, 20204.7, 24964.8, 29724.9, 34485.0, 39245.1, 44005.2,
              48765.3, 53525.4, 58285.5, 58968.2])

y = np.array([4.2, 4.086, 4.048, 3.984, 3.949, 3.909, 3.869, 3.802, 3.723,
              3.531, 3.0])

# polynomial fit
xx = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 500)
c = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit(x, y, 5)
yfit = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval(xx, c)

# plot
plt.ion()
plt.close('all')

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y, 'o-', alpha=0.4, label='data')
plt.plot(xx, yfit, label='fit')
plt.xlabel('x values')
plt.ylabel('y values')
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

This produces the following plot where the blue points are the data and the orange line is the polynomial fit from the example.
[image: polynomial fit]

I've tried different degrees for the polynomial but can't get a good fit with the data points. Is there a way to develop the polynomial fit with fixed data points using the Polynomial module in NumPy?

Comment: Do you want the polynomial to match exactly the values of the given data points, i.e. P(xx) = y for xx in x ?

Comment: @ma3oun The fit needs to include every data point.

Comment: NumPy 1.4? New? It's from almost a decade ago, around 2010 or the end of 2009 (the Github release date says Dec 27, 2009).

Comment: This data doesn't look like a polynomial is a sensible model.

Comment: @user2357112 What type of fit do you suggest I use for the data?

Comment: If you want your curve to go through every datapoint you probably do not want a fit, but an interpolation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html

Comment: I guess you are searching for a variant of spline interpolation. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called a  [Lagrange interpolation polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial). Scipy provides the necessary [function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.lagrange.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import lagrange

# data points to fit
x = np.array([11844.6, 20204.7, 24964.8, 29724.9, 34485.0, 39245.1, 44005.2,
          48765.3, 53525.4, 58285.5, 58968.2])

y = np.array([4.2, 4.086, 4.048, 3.984, 3.949, 3.909, 3.869, 3.802, 3.723,
          3.531, 3.0])

# polynomial fit
xx = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 500)

c=lagrange(x,y)
yfit = c(xx)

dataPointsDiff = c(x) - y
print(dataPointsDiff)
# plot
plt.ion()
plt.close('all')

plt.figure()  
plt.plot(x, y, 'o-', alpha=0.4, label='data')
plt.plot(xx, yfit, label='fit')
plt.xlabel('x values')
plt.ylabel('y values')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

> [-4.49746906e-11  5.29905009e-11  5.50018697e-10  2.20772201e-09
>     6.39017905e-09  1.55495092e-08  3.40470758e-08  6.83516173e-08
>     1.27306250e-07  2.27304275e-07  2.46438276e-07]

[image: Plot]

Keep in mind this results in a lot of ripple...

Comment: Maybe also add cubic interpolation to your example, which maybe looks more like what the OP expects.

Comment: This approach works for the middle points but the fit at the beginning and end is poor.

Comment: You can't have it both ways. Your model isn't a perfect polynomial fit. If you want something in between a perfect fit for your data points and that minimizes the euclidean distance, you need to write a custom cost function and it becomes an optimization problem...In any case, it won't change the reality of your data which is not a perfect polynomial fit.